# Offset ticks from the bar graph in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am using subplot in matplotlib to make bar graph currently showing data labels on top of the bars (in rotated position). Please see the image.

[image]

as per this the datalabels are touching the bars. Can they be offset to give some space between the bar and the datalabel. Following is my code. Please help.

```
x = df_graph3['Parameter2'].values
y1 = df_graph3['Vol Flow'].values

z1 = Figure(figsize=(2, 3), tight_layout=TRUE)
plot1 = z1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plot1.bar(x, y1, color='#EB3F3F')
plot1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

for i in range(len(x)):
    plot1.text(i, y1[i], y1[i], ha='center', va='bottom', size=8,rotation=90)

plot1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plot1.set_xticklabels(x, fontsize=8)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(z1, master=frame_dash3)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, sticky='nsew')
```

Comment: Are you talking about the int values like `88.64` and `8.74`? Can you just add, say, 1 to `y1[i]` ? Like `plot1.text(i, y1[i]+1, y1[i]+1, ha='center', va='bottom', size=8,rotation=90)`?

Comment: @MichaelS. I cant do it. Because it will change values of datalabels to be 88.64+1=89.64 and same with other datalabels

Comment: Whoops. Just add your value to the first `y[i]`. According to [the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), your first `y[i]` value is the text's position while the second `y[i]` value is the label. Like: `plot1.text(i, y1[i]+1, y1[i], ha='center', va='bottom', size=8,rotation=90)`

Comment: You should be using `matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`, which has a `padding=` parameters

Comment: The plot should be `ax = df.plot(kind='bar', x='Parameter2', y='Vol Flow', figsize=(2, 3))`, `ax.spines[['top', 'bottom', 'right', 'left']].set_visible(False)`, `ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], label_type='edge', rotation=90, fontsize=7, padding=3)`, `ax.margins(y=0.1)`.

Comment: Or assign df.plot to a specific existing subplot: `df.plot(kind='bar', x='Parameter2', y='Vol Flow', ax=plot1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the y value of `plot1.text(i, y[i]+1, ...)` This will increase the location of the text to 1 point. you can increase the space with increasing the value in `y[i]+your_value`

```
x = df_graph3['Parameter2'].values
y1 = df_graph3['Vol Flow'].values

z1 = Figure(figsize=(2, 3), tight_layout=TRUE)
plot1 = z1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plot1.bar(x, y1, color='#EB3F3F')
plot1.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
plot1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)

for i in range(len(x)):
    plot1.text(i, y1[i]+1, y1[i], ha='center', va='bottom', size=8,rotation=90)

plot1.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plot1.set_xticklabels(x, fontsize=8)

canvas1 = FigureCanvasTkAgg(z1, master=frame_dash3)
canvas1.draw()
canvas1.get_tk_widget().grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10, sticky='nsew')
```

Hope this'll work :)